# Ensuring or validating that a student can only vote once using my voting system. -VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to have a voting system where a registered student can only vote once. I have this code where I used the registered Firstname and Surname as their log-in access. Can you help me guys on how could I possibly make the student who voted already compromise his/her rights to vote twice? Thank you.

```
    Private Sub MetroButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MetroButton2.Click
    Dim sql As String

    If FirstName2MetroTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Type in your First Name.")
    ElseIf SurnameMetroTextBox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Type in your Surname.")
    Else

        Try
            If FirstName2MetroTextBox.Text = "" And SurnameMetroTextBox.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("First Name and Surname doesn't match.")
            Else
                sql = "select * from student_registrants where Firstname = '" & FirstName2MetroTextBox.Text & "' and Surname = '" & SurnameMetroTextBox.Text & "'"
                With cmd
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandText = sql
                End With
                Timer1.Start()






                da.Dispose()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        conn.Clone()

    End If
End Sub
```

and it will eventually log-in to my Voting Form. After he/she picks his/her desired candidate, I made this code.

```
    Private Sub TileItem26_ItemClick(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileItemEventArgs) Handles ConfirmTileItem.ItemClick
    If PresidentMetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next President.")
    ElseIf VicePresidentMetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Vice President.")
    ElseIf SecretaryMetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Secretary.")
    ElseIf AuditorMetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Auditor.")
    ElseIf Senator1MetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Senator(s).")
    ElseIf Senator2MetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Senator(s).")
    ElseIf Senator3MetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Senator(s).")
    ElseIf Senator4MetroLabel.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Choose your next Senator(s).")

    Else
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;password=;database=university_election")
            conn.Open()
            With cmd

                .Connection = conn
                .CommandText = "UPDATE `election_tally_presidents` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE President_ID = '" & presidentint & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_vicepresidents` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE VicePresident_ID = '" & vicepresidentint & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_secretary` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Secretary_ID = '" & secretaryint & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_auditor` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Auditor_ID = '" & auditorint & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_senators` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Senator_ID = '" & senator1int & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_senators` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Senator_ID = '" & senator2int & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_senators` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Senator_ID = '" & senator3int & "'; UPDATE `election_tally_senators` SET Votes = Votes + 1 WHERE Senator_ID = '" & senator4int & "';"
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                Timer1.Start()
                MetroProgressBar1.Show()
                MetroLabel1.Visible = True



            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Cannot register to the database: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try



    End If
End Sub
```

So what's the code that would best fit for my system? Thank you.

Comment: Add a boolean `Voted` column to your database.  When they vote, set the flag to true.  They can still vote more than once if they know someone else's name.

Comment: Ontop of the Boolean, do the students have unique ID's you could possibly use as their login access? What if someone has the same name? How will decide which one is voting, would your database just mark both people as voted?

Comment: Thank you for the response people and sweet suggestions. Well, actually I've changed my login access into IDNumber as their username and LastName as their password in order to avoid duplication of entries. I've also set the IDNumber to AUTO-INCREMENT to avoid duplications on my IDNumber database. @user3697824, may I ask for the code sir if it is okay with you. Thank you very much!

Comment: and by which means where should I insert the code sir? Thank you.